# Find a $\mathbb Q $-basis of $\mathbb Q( \omega, 2^{(1/3)})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Find a $\mathbb Q $-basis of $\mathbb Q( \omega, 2^{(1/3)})$.

It's easy to find $[ \mathbb Q( \omega, 2^{1/3}) :\mathbb Q]$ but how can I find the basis of $\mathbb Q( \omega, 2^{1/3})$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Please give me some hints.

Comment: Are you familiar with the product formula? If $K\subset L\subset F$ are fields, then $[F:K]=[F:L]\cdot [L:K]$. Its proof gives a way of constructing a $K$-basis of $F$ given an $L$-basis of $F$ and a $K$-basis of $L$. Comes in handy here. Particularly if you know how to construct a basis of $K(a)/K$ when $a$ is algebraic.

Comment: It would be better if you added the definition of Q-basis or something like that...

Comment: $\mathbb Q$-basis means 'a basis over the field $\mathbb Q$'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can express the extension as a series of simple extensions, then the basis is any multiplication of basis elements for those extensions.
(what is $\omega$?)

Comment: Here $\omega= e^{{2 \pi i }/3}$